# Python: Convert SQL query to pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a below sql query, I need to achieve the same logic.
Note: I have a dataframe with the mentioned columns.

```
SQL LOGIC:

Count(id)  where status='Pending' and type='truckroll' and ticket_created_time>today-52 week
```

I've tried the below code:

```
# Filter for truck roll 
df = df[df[type']=='truckroll']
# Filter only for status      
df= df[df[status']=='pending']

df1=df.groupby(["id"]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

I'm not able to get **ticket_created_time>today-52 week**
Is there any better way to get the same logic?

Comment: You can binary-and the different parts together. Just be aware of parenthesizing the individual parts): `df[(df['status'] == 'pending') & (df['type'] == 'truckroll') & (df['ticket_created'] > (today - 52))]`

Comment: what format are the `ticket_created_time` values in?

Comment: (Note that `today - 52 week` doesn't mean anything. you probably mean to compare to 52 weeks ago (or 1 year?), but we'd first need to know what type `ticket_created` is in the first place. A datetime, or a string?

Comment: Provided `ticket_created_time` is a `datetime64[ns]` (i.e., a Pandas datetime), *and* `today` is a datetime object, you can use `(today - df.ticket_created_time).dt.days < 52*7`.

Comment: I don't see the need for groupby: once you've done your three selections (possibly in one go, see my first comment), the length of the resulting dataframe is your count.

Comment: Or even simpler, to just get the count: `count = sum((df['status'] == 'pending') & (df['type'] == 'truckroll') & (today - df['ticket_created'].days < 52*7))`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply!! Ticket created time is in string format which is in YYYY-MM-DD format.  I should achieve this in string format, because I would suppose to use this result in further logic where I should have only YYYY-MM-DD @9769953.

Comment: Curious though: what further processing/logic are you aiming to do with just a YYYY-MM-DD string. Because it is very likely you can still do that processing with an actual date-time object (just ignoring the time part), and potentially even simpler.